# how to create and run a script in ubuntu that runs and than close a c code every 5 minutes

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have a c code that monitors a folder (the c code has a while(1) and prints events plus other stuff). I need to create a script that runs the executable for this c code. it is possible to create a script that runs in the backup as long as the computer is opened?
My c code contains a monitor file and executes a command line.

Need some help. I am new to scripts.Thx appreciat

Comment: "a script that runs the executable"? You mean like a boot script, that starts your application on system start, and kills your application on system shut down?

Comment: http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial I'm not that familiar with it but you need to make a script file .sh and run the script with ./script.sh and it looks like if you use echo that will execute your prog

Comment: Does your script need to compile the C program and run it, or just run the binary executable? Shell scripting or any other scripting language (ruby, python)?

Comment: it just need to compile the executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case

```
#!/bin/sh
./executable_name
```

(be sure to set the executable bit (x) for this file)

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out the error in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to-do.  A shell-script to run a problem can be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash

./my_program ##or path to executable unless its already in your environment
```

And then after creating it, make sure to set its executable bit through something like `chmod +x myscript.sh`.

Comment: This currently will not work as it is missing ./ (or whatever the path to the executable is).

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming the binary search path was already in the environment (i.e, /usr/bin/, etc.)

Comment: thx for reply. i don;t understand. what do you mean by /usr/bin? My executable is in /home/desktop/exe

Comment: This means that if the executable path is already in your environment, you don't have to add the entire path, you simply just write the name of the executable.  For instance, any executable in /usr/bin is already in your environment's executable search path ... so you can simply write things like `ls`, `cd`, etc. without having to write out `/usr/bin/ls`, or `/usr/bin/cd`.  Your home directory on the other-hand is probably not in the search path unless you've specifically added it.

Answer (score -1):

First create an executable out of your C code using gcc, say the exe ist called MyExe. Then you may use a bash script in following form:

```
#!/bin/sh

./MyExe
```

This script assumes that your execuatable is in the same directory as this bash script. 
And now make your script executable by using this:

```
chmod 755 your_script_file
```

Creating an exe out of your C code can be done in simplest way as follows:

```
gcc MyExe.c -l[a lib you need to link into your exe] -o MyExe
```

Now you can call your script using this:

```
./your_script_file
```